# Is there a way for the lock screen to be just like the login screen in Lubuntu 18.10?

Tags: lubuntu, lock-screen, screensaver

I've noticed that when I set the screensaver to 'Blank Screen Only' after a few minutes of idleness and check 'Lock Screen After' the actual login dialog is the XScreensaver one (which in my opinion looks terrible). So is there a way for the lock screen to look just like the login screen you see every time you boot up the system? On Linux Mint it worked out of the box: after some time, the screen went black an if one would move the mouse or press some key, they would be greeted with the same login screen as when they first booted up. Does anyone know how to help me?
Thanks.